# How to have a circular button with background image (Swift 4)

Tags: swift4

I have a circular button that I want to display an image through the photo library, but when I give it a background image it turns back into a square. I need to know how to have a button be both circular and contain a background image.

Comment: Can you please post the code you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
YourbuttonObject.layer.cornerRadius = YourbuttonObject.frame.height/2
YourbuttonObject.clipsToBounds = true
```

Now when you will set a `backgroundImage` it will be circular

or you can use a `ImageView` and use it like a button and set a `backgroundImage` for it and do

```
YourImageObject.layer.cornerRadius = YourImageObject.frame.height/2
YourIamgeObject.clipsToBounds = true
```